# how to validate html elements with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to validate an HTML element (a text field) whose `id` is dynamically assigned through an array. I have given my HTML code below. Please give me a direction on how to set the HTML `id` in jQuery?

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="property in entity.entityPropertyTypes">
    <!-- PROPERTY -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label">{property.propertyLabel}}</label>
    </div>

    <!-- VALUE -->
    <!-- Text field -->
    <div class="col-md-3" ng-if="property.dataTypeId === 3 ">
        <input id="{{property.propertyId}}Value" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="property.propertyValue">
    </div>

    <!-- Date -->               
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1" ng-if="property.dataTypeId === 4 ">
        <datepicker date-format="MM-yyyy"> 
            <input id="{{property.propertyId}}yearEnd" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="property.propertyValue">
        </datepicker>
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you doing the validation?

Comment: We can use siblings or parents this way: `$('div>datepicker>input')` (to get to the second `input` tag).

Comment: I am doing the validation using jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can add any property you want and then use a selector to get the element.

For example, you could add a class to the input:

```
 <input id="{{property.propertyId}}Value" type="text" class="form-control myclass" ng-model="property.propertyValue">
```

and then select by class

```
 var textToCheck = $("input.myclass").val();
```

You can even add a personal attribute:

```
 <input item="1" id="{{property.propertyId}}Value" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="property.propertyValue">
```

and then

```
var textToCheck = $("input[item=1]").val();
```